# Why is there a need for an explicit Initialize method when you can just initialize in the constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, initialization, viewmodel

I'm doing the following:

```
var vm = scope.CreateInstance<IBlaBla>();

vm.SetTitles("bla"); //anti pattern
vm.Initialize(foo, bar);
```

I'm being told that the above is an anti-pattern because I should **never** invoke another method before invoking the Initialize method. So, solution is to pass another argument to the Initialize method and make that method do the SetTitles work.

I can see the logic behind this as you want to make sure the VM is properly initialized before doing anything with it. But why can't the initialise work be done when we created a new instance of the VM? I don't understand the need for an explicit Initialize method. When would this be an advantage?

Comment: Because state of vm is uninitialized when you settitles and your change may be overriden inside initialize method. And if your settitles method is part of initialization of vm, why would you not do all initialization in single method?

Comment: @VikciaR Okay I understand, but why not initialize the state when you create an instance of the VM?

Comment: From the dictionary: *initialize: set to the value or put in the condition appropriate to the start of an operation.*. So it is probably confusing to call that anywhere but at the start of your operation.

Comment: An initialize method is useful when you cannot initialize your instance in the constructor, e.g. because there are dependecies to things that are themselves not properly initialized or not existent at the time the instance is constructed.

Comment: I would say that your service locator can also be considered an anit-pattern. But what is and isn't an anit-pattern is debatable. Better question is why not use this or that then is something an anit-pattern

Comment: @DSF: it's up to you to decide. Personally I use initialize very rare - when that initialization is pretty big or takes time. It's my personal taste - I prefer to make initialization inside constructor.

Comment: I don't understand the need for an explicit Initialize method. When would this be an advantage? Well I see it being useful when init is async. And If you need to do some heavy server stuff you might want to do it on different thread without you view model being aware of it.

Comment: Funny how one close vote will make others vote close as well who wouldn't have done it otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make sure that the view model is *always* properly initialized before doing anything with it you should consider making its constructor private and provide a factory method that both creates an instance of it an initializes it:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ViewModel(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }

    public static ViewModel CreateAndInitialize(string title)
    {
        return new ViewModel(title);
    }
}
```

Then you will always have a property initialized instance:

```
ViewModel vm = ViewModel.CreateAndInitialize("...");
```

This approach is especially useful if the view model is asynchronously initialized:

```
public static async Task<ViewModel> CreateAndInitializeAsync(string title)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000); //do some init work...
    return new ViewModel(title);
}
```

---

```
ViewModel vm = await ViewModel.CreateAndInitializeAsync("...");
```

Otherwise you may usually do the initialization in the constructor of the view model and then you don't need any `Initialize` method at all.

Comment: `static ViewModel Initialize` is a factory pattern not an Initialiser so should be called Create not Initialize

Comment: Or CreateAndInitialize if you intend to always return an initialized instance. I changed the name for clarification.

Comment: what if you want to use any services in initialize method?

Comment: Then you could just inject the method with these services.

Comment: I don't get it. If it's static you won't be able to use them in initialize method. So I guess the logic should be moved to a separate factory class which will be responsible for creating an initializing view model. Correct?

Comment: You will be able to use a service exactly the same way as you use the string in my example. The static method creates and instance of the class and may pass anything it want to its constructor. Separate factory class...? No.

Answer (score 0):

your question "why can't the initialise work be done when we created a new instance of the VM?"

lets assume a vm declared as

```
var vm = new VM(){
    prop1 = "foo",
    prop2 = "bar"
};
vm.Initialise();
```

now what is happening here

1. Construction
2. Configuration
3. Initialisation

this means that if you initialise inside the constructor configuration can't occur

keeping initialisation separate from construction also makes it easier for designer support as it can create objects for reflection that are none functional and hence less likely to crash because of dependencies

this is also why empty constructors are required for designer support